# Adding Entire Gutenberg Editor in Standalone Plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

In one of my plugins I'm currently developing ([TargetPop](https://wordpress.org/plugins/targetpop/)), I've embedded the TinyMCE editor so that the user can create contents for their Pop-Up, complete with both the 'Visual' and 'Text' views, and the ability to add media, style/formatting options, etc. See screenshot below.

My question is: How would I replicate this entire functionality with the upcoming Gutenberg Editor? I found tons of examples of how to create a new block for Gutenberg, but nothing really about embedding the entire Gutenberg editor somewhere else, like I've embedded the TinyMCE editor. I probably just missed this info somewhere... any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Maybe should you simply use a custom post-type, because Gutenberg uses the REST API to save content.

With a CPT, you'll have all the Gutenberg UI and a better integration.

Comment: @BastienHo I'm also searching for a way to implement Gutenberg as the editor in my custom plugin. I create a new post type in my plugin, but still shows the old editor instead.

Comment: @MirandaBreekweg it should be a standalone question. But for editing a CPT in Gutenberg, it just have to support the REST API when you register it. Hope it helps

Comment: @BastienHo yeah figured it out a while ago and placed the solution as an answer in here (below)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a register_post_type() in your plugin, add

```
'show_in_rest' => true
```

to the arguments array of it and make sure 'editor' is in the supports array of the arguments array.